# VBA Excel - From formula to list

Tags: excel, vba, defined

I have a formula with defined names

```
=AVERAGE(DN1,DN2,DN3,DN4)
```

Is there any formula/function to give me those defined names in a table? So something looking like

```
Header
DN1
DN2
DN3
DN4
```

Thanks

Comment: See [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/251590/how-to-see-all-of-the-named-cell-ranges-in-an-excel-workbook/) if it helps. This gives all named ranges in workbook.

Comment: Thanks for tip, I didn't know about that option but it is not what I was looking for. I have names from DN1 to DN38 and not all the variations are used in a given formula; I only want those used in a specific formula.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA `Range("A1").Formula` will return the formula contained in cell `A1` as string of text.

With a bit more VBA you should be able to parse that text to get you the names you want and to list them on an appropriate bit of worksheet.

The ease with which you will be able to do this will depend on the amount of variety you have in the formulae which you want to analyse.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I have been able to achieve the job using a couple of user defined functions, the use of array and its Split function. If anyone wants any help give me a shout. Thanks anyway to all of you who tried to help. CM